# How can I write a regex to repeatedly capture group within a larger match?

Tags: windows, regex, grep

I'm getting a regex headache, so hopefully someone can help me here. I'm doing some file syntax conversion and I've got this situation in the files:

```
OpenMarker
    keyword some expression
    keyword some expression
    keyword some expression
    keyword some expression
    keyword some expression
CloseMarker
```

I want to match all instances of "keyword" inside the markers. The marker areas are repeated and the keyword can appear in other places, but I don't want to match outside of the markers. What I don't seem to be able to work out is how to get a regex to pull out all the matches. I can get one to do the first or the last, but not to get all of them. I believe it should be possible and it's something to do with repeated capture groups -- can someone show me the light?

I'm using grepWin, which seems to support all the bells and whistles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
(?<=OpenMarker((?!CloseMarker).)*)keyword(?=.*CloseMarker)
```

this will match the `keyword` inside `OpenMarker` and `CloseMarker` (using the option "dot matches newline").

Comment: Good idea, if grepWin supports infinite repetition inside lookbehind.

Comment: It doesn't seem to support variable length lookbehind. I'm going to roll my own code in .NET to gain access to a regex engine that has this feature but I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -n -e '/OpenMarker[[:space:]]*CloseMarker/p' /path/to/file | grep keyword` should work.  Not sure if `grep` alone could do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are only a few regex engines that support separate captures of a repeated group (.NET for example). So your best bet is to do this in two steps:

First match the section you're interested in: `OpenMarker(.*?)CloseMarker` (using the option "dot matches newline").

Then apply another regex to the match repeatedly: `keyword (.*)` (this time without the option "dot matches newline").