# Regex to repeatedly capture group within a larger match?

Tags: regex, pcre, gedit

Context, syntax highlighting in gedit.

**Problem:** I want to capture all occurrences within a specific area. Toy example:

```
other text here $5
keyword1 ->  (( ran$3dom$6t:,ext$9    ))
keyword1  -> ((    ran$2dom$4t:,ext$6 ))
other text here $7
```

I want to capture (highlight) al the $0-9 (single digit) occurrences, within the `(( text ))` of the `keyword1`. (here `$3`, `$6`, `$9`, `$2`, `$4`, `$6` but **NOT** `$5` and `$7`). This boils down to: How can I repeatedly capture a group within a larger match?

I can grab all the text where the groups can occur with: `(?<=keyword1)|\(\(.*\)\)` (gedit uses \g by default)

```
<context id="keyword1" style-ref="argument">
  <match>(?<=keyword1)|\(\(.*\)\)</match>
</context>
```

I have found this related question: [How can I write a regex to repeatedly capture group within a larger match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480862/how-can-i-write-a-regex-to-repeatedly-capture-group-within-a-larger-match) but that answer uses infinite repetition inside look-behind which is, unfortunately, not supported by gedit (as far as i know). Any suggestion?

Comment: If gedit supports PCRE you can use a \G based regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

To ensure you're only working on lines starting with your keyword, then I see this as a two step operation.

1. collect each of the lines you're interested
2. extract the `$[0-9]` substrings

## Step 1

This regular expression captures lines that resemble `keyword1 -> ((...))`

```
keyword1\s*->\s*\(\(.*\)\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Step 2

```
\$[0-9](?![0-9])(?=(?:(?!\(\().)*\)\))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- find all dollar signs followed by a single digit that exist inside the `((...))`

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/wY3jM6/1

**Sample text**

```
other text here $5
keyword1 ->  (( ran$3dom$6t:,ext$9    ))
keyword1  -> ((    ran$2dom$4t:,ext$6 ))
other text here $7
```

**Sample Matches**

```
$3
$6
$9
$2
$4
$6
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \$                       '$'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks you for your (well explained) response, the regex indeed captures all the required $[0-9] occurrences but it does not takes into account the 'keyword1'. Your suggested regex fails  if i substitute the second keyword1 with keyword2 (so it should not capture the $2, $4 and $6) but it does. Unfortunately my trick with | (see opening post regex) does not work with your regex.